# Android StaggeredGridView Issue

Tags: android, android-gridview, staggered-gridview

I want GridView like [pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/), for that I have implemented [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/) lib.

In that i got problem of scrolling. when i scrolling up, the top image are move to next row and top view is going to blank.

I have post issue in following link with image.

### [Stuck with this Issue of StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/issues/78)

**Note:**

If i fixed height of ImageView, Its works perfectly but not getting that view which i want.

How can i fix this problem.?

[image]

Your Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been long to answer this but now **Recyclerview** Supports different **layoutmanager** so for using staggered with recyclerview **just use below code**:-

```
 rcyclerview.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

And if you want to add this as your header then on bindviewholder in your header part set below code :-

```
 StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
```